# Repeat command and increase range

Tags: vba, excel

I have almost no experience with VBA that being said.
I have a function in "B21" that I have copied over the same row up to "Z21"
I want the results from these cells to be shown on a different sheet all in one Column starting at "B2" and repeating until till it reaches the end.
This is what I have for that.

```
Sheets("Barlist").Range("B2").Value = "B21"
```

Alternatively the function I have in "B21" that I have copied over to repeat itself is:

```
=IF((COLUMN()-1)<$B$16,ROUND(TAN(RADIANS($B$5))*(($B$6)-($B$15*(COLUMN()-2))),2)+($B$11-0.33),IF((COLUMN()-1)=$B$16,$B$18,""))
```

So if I could just tell in to repeat this function down Column "B" until it returns a blank result that would should work to.

Comment: There are variables that go into the IF function I provided that would change how many of the cells B21:Z21 get populated. I want only the cells populated to show up on Sheets("Barlist") and when this function stops I have another function that I want to start in the next blank cell after the results.

Comment: You are saying this range range B21:Z21 has formulas that sometimes return blank cells?  And that you want nonblank cells to copy into column B on a separate sheet ("Barlist")? Then you want to do something else with the blank cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would cycle through all cells from B21 to the last column in row 21 with data and if the cell is blank you would need to add the code for what you wanted to do with that cell.  Otherwise, the cells gets placed into "Barlist" starting at B2 and working down (using the next blank row each time)

```
Sub NAMEOFSUB()

Dim LastCol As Long
Dim CurCol As Long
Dim DestRow As Long

LastCol = Sheets("CURRENT SHEET NAME").Cells(21, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For CurCol = 2 to LastCol
    If Sheets("CURRENT SHEET NAME").Cells(21, CurCol).Value = "" Then
        'Do Something with your blank cell such as add a .Formula
    Else
        DestRow = Sheets("Barlist").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheets("Barlist").Range("B" & DestRow).Value = Sheets("CURRENT SHEET NAME").Cells(2, CurCol).Value
    End If
Next CurCol

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this out but it is stopping after 2 cells. There are still another 10 with data based on current variables.

Comment: My bad... I have `Cells(2, CurCol).Value` should be `Cells(21, CurCol).Value` and same with `.Cells(2, Columns.Count).` should be `.Cells(21, Columns.Count).`  I will update my code.

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?
Right now your code would just enter the value "B21" in cell B2 on sheet Barlist.

If you want to add a reference to that cell, you could use `Sheets("Barlist").Range("B2").FormulaR1C1="R21C2"`

Although I really don't see any reason to use VBA at all for this.  If you want a dynamic range, so it is *linked* to the original range, you could simply use the [Transpose Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/transpose-function-HP010069834.aspx).

For your example, select the cells B2 to B26 on your Barlist sheet.  Press F2 (should enter cell B2) and enter the formula `=TRANSPOSE(SHEET!B21:Z21).`  This is an array function, so you don't just press enter, you have to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER at the same time to enter it. Excel will automatically append little curly brackets `{}` around the formula so you know it's an array formula.

If you want static values, select the range B21:Z21 you want to copy, then go to cell B2 on your Barlist sheet and right click>paste special and use the "trasnpsose" option